# Can a non muslim who believes in one God Allah read a quran in his language keep the holy book respectfully in hi house?

Tags: non-muslim

As Salam Aleikhum friends can a non muslim who believes in one God Allah and in all the prophets including prophet Muhamned  read a quran in his language keep the holy book respectfully in his house?.I am referring to me because I believe in Allah.

Comment: First only the Arabic version is considered as quran and shouldn't be touched by non-Muslims according the most orthodox views. Secondly a translation is only an interpretation which may miss some meanings and nuances.

Comment: If you believe in one and only one god Allah and in all the prophets and believe that prophet muhammed (peace be upon him ) is the messenger of Allah then you are no more non Muslim .. :)